# Listener on change other page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, listener

We want to notify the user when there is a change on the server. The user is logged in on a page:

```
index.php
```

And there is a file that receives all changed data from another server in JSON:

```
receiver.php
```

How do i notify the specific user that there is a change in the data. I'm aware of browser notification, but that is by far implemented on all browsers.

Maybe i can set a jQuery/javascript listener, to listen for events for a specific page.

I can also save my changes in a database. By querying the database every 5 seconds i can check those changes, but i think there is a better way.

So how do i update the session of this user.

Comment: may be you can try **LONG POLLING** (I mean AJAX request in the background with long polling )

Comment: @oritm , Look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code